# What is document id in DocuSign? how can i get it?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I want to send a document to recipient for signing the doc with Docusign API. but in API documentation I have seen that there has a field called documentId

```
$data = 
  array (
    "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Please sign " . $documentName,
    "documents" => array( 
        array("documentId" => "1", "name" => $documentName)
        ),
    "recipients" => array( 
        "signers" => array(
            array(
                "email" => $recipientEmail,
                "name" => $recipientName,
                "recipientId" => "1",
                "tabs" => array(
                    "signHereTabs" => array(
                        array(
                            "xPosition" => "100",
                            "yPosition" => "100",
                            "documentId" => "1",
                            "pageNumber" => "1"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
  "status" => "sent"
);
```

But i can't understand, how can i get this.

Comment: I think you need to mark Amit's answer below as the correct answer. It is the nice thing to do for Amit.

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing document bytes in DS API call, then you can set documentId as any positive number starting from 1. The documentId which you will set in "documents" node, you have to refer the same while assigning tabs for the recipients. Like in your code, you have set documentId as 1 and same you are referring when adding tabs for recipients.

Comment: Can all documents ever sent all have the same documentId. So if I send one file for one Envelope and give it "1", then a week later the app sends a different document and in that Envelope and give it a "1" as a documentId for that one as well? Or do all documents ever sent to DocuSign for a particular App have unique Document Ids? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, found this to explain that yes, many envelopes can have a documentId ="1". https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/templates/templatedocuments/get/